# Pipeline Nuget restore failing on .Net Core 3.0 Preview 8 project (NU1202)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I updated a project from netcoreapp2.2 to netcoreapp3.0 and use Preview8 SDK as well as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, tools, and design.

I can build and run my projects locally just find (VS 2019). But when I try to deploy with Azure DevOps, the Nuget restore gives this error:

> NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Every reference to an EntityFrameworkCore package will result in that error.

I'm setting the .Net Core SDK in the pipeline to Preview8 via a global.json.

I have a NuGet tool installer task, bringing in the latest version, and a Nuget Restore task command running against my solution.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 16):

My problem was that I was using the Nuget Restore. Changing it to dotnet restore made the trick.

[image]

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

This problem is caused by an **obsolete version of NuGet agent**.

Use NuGet Install Tool task (a.k.a. Use NuGet) and setup the agent to the v5.x.

[image: Update of NuGet Build Agent.]

This is a **low profile** solution.

Comment: This fixed it for me - was using Nuget 4.6 for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Yay, I have enough rep to comment now.

It turns out the easier fix is to updatethe NuGet package version to the latest (5.3.0) in the "Use NuGet" task.

---

Not enough rep to comment on Fernando's response but it worked for me.

Edit the pipeline's Agent tasks:

- add .NET Core, Display name: dotnet restore, Command: restore
- set up other properties pretty much the same as the existing NuGet Restore
- remove NuGet restore

Answer (score 2):

> Pipeline Nuget restore failing on .Net Core 3.0 Preview 8 project (NU1202)

If you are using the host agent, you should make sure you have install the netcoreapp3.0 on the agent. You could use the task `Use .NET Core` to install it:

[image]

Note check the option `Include Preview Versions`.

Note: Since netcoreapp3.0 supported by Visual Studio 2019, so, you need to make sure your agent is **Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019**.

Hope this helps.