# NuGet restore fore solution to get wix getting failed in Azure Devops

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, nuget-package

While running the `wpf UI tests` the following task 'NuGet restore fore solution to get wix' getting failed in Azure Devops with below errors. Could someone please advise on how to resolve the errors ?

[image]

```
  Installed:
        1 package(s) to packages.config projects
    ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in c:\agent\_work\9\s\tests\MediaApp.Wpf.UiTests\MediaApp.Wpf.UiTests.csproj
        Package Appium.WebDriver 3.0.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Appium.WebDriver 3.0.0.2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
        Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1 supports:
          - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
          - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
        Package Selenium.Support 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Selenium.Support 3.0.1 supports:
          - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
          - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
        Package Castle.Core 3.3.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Castle.Core 3.3.3 supports:
          - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
          - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
          - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
          - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
          - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
        Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 4.6.0-preview8.19405.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 4.6.0-preview8.19405.3 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0.

    Errors in c:\agent\_work\9\s\src\MediaApp.Wpf\MediaApp.Wpf.csproj
        Package AutoMapper 8.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package AutoMapper 8.1.0 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.1 supports:
          - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF 2.0.20525 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF 2.0.20525 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
        Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.2.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.2.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter 4.5.0 supports:
          - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
          - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
          - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
          - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
          - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
          - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
        Package System.Drawing.Common 4.5.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.Drawing.Common 4.5.1 supports:
          - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
          - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
          - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
          - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
          - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
          - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
        Package System.Management 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.Management 4.5.0 supports:
          - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.5.0 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 4.5.0 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        Package System.CodeDom 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package System.CodeDom 4.5.0 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0.

    Errors in c:\agent\_work\9\s\tests\MediaApp.Wpf.Tests\MediaApp.Wpf.Tests.csproj
        Package AutoMapper 8.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package AutoMapper 8.1.0 supports:
          - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
          - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

Comment: You have a clear error here, that a lot of packages aren't compatible with .NET core 3

Comment: first of all, why do you use 3.0 preview while 3.1 LTS is out.
secondly, the error couldn't be clearer: you must update your dependencies.

Comment: I have updated the Nuget packages as someone suggested me, but that didn't work as some of these packages are major versions updates with different APIs - so the code would need to be updated to fix this, so I have to revert the nuget updates. Later I have installed `dotnet-sdk-3.0.101-win-x64.exe` and give a restart. But still I got the error `The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0.` Now I have updated the Visual Studio to latest version and error disappeared.

Comment: @soccerway Hi friend, does the original issue persists to block you? And which agent do you use, microsoft-hosted agent or private agent? The nuget restore task does similar things like what `dotnet restore` do locally, so if the local restore fails, it would be expected behavior that the online task fails too.

Comment: Yes original issue still there... tests are running in local. But not running in Azure pipeline. After creating a pull request, i got 2 errors in `NuGet restore fore solution to get wix`- don't know the reason yet.

Comment: Hmm, according to the name 'NuGet restore fore solution to get wix' , do you use [nuget restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)?  Try using [Use .net core 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) task+[dotnet restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) cause your projects all target .net core 3.0, can it make any difference?

Comment: @soccerway Just checking in to see whether my answer could help to resolve this issue, if it still persists, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT .Thank you very much. Option 1 given in your answer (Use .Net Core sdk 3.x) helped me to resolve half of my problem, the other problem was due to our hosted VM shut down. All good now.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)

Comment: Awesome help mate, I was struggling last day to know what was the problem of failure, deploying to dev actually work but Test fails. It screwed up my whole day. Anyway one last question why do we need to use 'dotnet restore' in the Agent ? I don't have one in mine.. Is that required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Package xxx is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0

If all projects in your solution targets `.net core`, please use `Use .net core task+dotnet restore` like this:

[image]

If your solution contains projects that target `.net core+.net framework`, then you can use `Use nuget+nuget restore` like this:

[image]

You should specify the version of nuget.exe to use. Nuget 5.3.1 is the version that works well in my pipeline. Also, you can choose to enable the `Always download the latest matching version` box. See similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501716/pipeline-nuget-restore-failing-on-net-core-3-0-preview-8-project-nu1202).

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.
>   Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 3.0.

It indicates you should use the agent with `VS2019+corresponding .net core sdk` to run the restore. If you're using microsoft-hosted agent, you should use the `window 2019` agent when you queue the build pipeline. You'll meet the issue if you use `VS2017-Window2016` agent.

Also you should make sure you've installed same or higher versions of .net core sdk.(link [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral)). You can install corresponding sdk manually before queuing the pipeline if you're using private agent, or use `Use .net core 3.x task` if you're using hosted agent.