# Create a NuGet package of a netcore 3.0 project which is dependent upon netstandard packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, .net-standard

My solution consist of many projects targeting `netcore 3.0`, some of these projects have reference to other nuget packages which targets `netstandard 2.0`.

I want to create one nuget package of a project referencing other projects. In my Azure DevOps pipeline I have the following task to build the `nupkg` file

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Create NuGet Package'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'Core.Hosting/Core.Hosting.nuspec'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    includeReferencedProjects: true
    includeSymbols: true
```

Followed by a task to push to artifacts in Azure Devops:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'reference-to-feed-is-removed'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq('true', variables['PUSH_TO_NUGET']))
```

My nuspec file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Core Hosting</id>
    <version>1.0.0-prerelease-5.0.0</version>
    <title>Core Hosting</title>
    <authors>Core Team</authors>
    <owners>My Company a/s</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <projectUrl>project-url-removed/projectUrl>
    <description>Core backend components to interact with various services in Azure.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.0">
        <dependency id="AspNetCore.Firebase.Authentication" version="2.0.1"/>
        <dependency id="Autofac" version="4.9.4"/>
        <dependency id="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="5.0.1"/>
        <dependency id="Autofac.Mef" version="4.1.0"/>
        <dependency id="LinqKit.Core" version="1.1.17"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" version="2.12.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.12.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" version="3.0.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" version="5.0.0"/>
        <dependency id="System.ComponentModel.Composition" version="4.6.0"/>
        <dependency id="System.Composition.AttributedModel" version="1.3.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.12.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" version="2.2.5"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="3.0.4"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" version="1.3.1"/>
        <dependency id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="4.6.0"/>
        <dependency id="FirebaseAdmin" version="1.9.1"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.OpenApi" version="1.1.4"/>
        <dependency id="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" version="5.0.0"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="3.1.1"/>
        <dependency id="SendGrid" version="9.12.0"/>
        <dependency id="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" version="6.0.0-develop.2244"/>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="3.0.14"/>
        <dependency id="System.ComponentModel.Composition" version="4.6.0"/>
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I want to use this nuget package in my other netcore 3.0 project, which works perfectly locally by adding it from the `Nuget Package Manager`. Everything build and run as expected except when I try to run the pipeline for this project:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "*"

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install dotnet 3.x SDK'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: '3.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'feed-id-removed'

- script: dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName~UnitTests
  displayName: "Run Unit Tests"

- script: dotnet publish Example.Service.Host/Example.Service.Host.csproj --configuration Release -o 'output/publish' --runtime linux-x64 -f netcoreapp3.0
  displayName: "Build Example.Service"

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: ''
    Contents: 'Dockerfile'
    TargetFolder: 'output'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: 'Example.Service/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'Example.Service/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Running the NuGet restore task in my pipeline, I errors complaining about compatability issues like this one:

```
Package AspNetCore.Firebase.Authentication 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Package AspNetCore.Firebase.Authentication 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0
```

All of errors are the same, the dependent package X is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 as it targets netstandard2.0.

I find i quite strange that it works locally when building and restoring packages in Visual Studio, but not when I run it from the pipeline. I also thought that libraries which targets `netstandard2.0` would be compatible with `netcoreapp3.0` apps

Is there a way I can get this to work in my Azure Devops pipeline or have I screwed up big time?

Comment: A quick look over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support also suggests that Standard 2.0 is not compatible with Core 3.0. Have you tried making it Standard 2.1?

Comment: Making what Standard 2.1? We have dusins of dependencies fetched from nuget.org which is netstandard 2.0. Why does this compile and work locally, but not on the virtual ubuntu machine that the pipeline runs on?

Comment: An artical states the following: In theory, you shouldn't need to change your library at all. .NET Core 3.0 supports .NET Standard 2.1, and by extension, it supports .NET Standard 2.0.

Reference: https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/

Comment: As to why it's running locally and not in the pipeline - we're having the same conundrum in our company. For our cases, however, often when building the solution from MSBuild in cmd directly (as Azure Pipelines are doing, really), rather than from Visual studio we the same errors that the pipeline is showing us, so we can at least reproduce them locally. MSBuild and Visual Studio build ought to be almost identical with just some small overhead on the Visual Studio one, but apparently that makes difference enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by an obsolete version of NuGet agent. You can try using [NuGet Install Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) task and setup the agent to the v5.x, before using NuGetCommand restore task.

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x
    checkLatest: true
```

Another possible fix is to use dotnet restore instead of nuget restore.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'azure feed'
```

You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501716/pipeline-nuget-restore-failing-on-net-core-3-0-preview-8-project-nu1202) for more details.

Comment: You are correct. It helped installing the NugetToolInstaller in my pipeline. Thanks!